# Как выбрать ключ из объекта, у которого наибольшее значение?

Tags: javascript

Есть некий объект:

```
{
    "1PC": 14,
    "1PC10": 22
}
```

Нужно выбрать из него ключ, в котором указано наибольшее значение. Т.е. в данном примере алгоритм должен вернуть строку `1PC10`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать например так :

```js
const o = {
  "1PC": 14,
  "1PC10": 22
}

const getMaxKey = obj => {
  // ищем максимальное значение
  const maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(obj))
  // фильтруем по максимальному значению массив ключей
  return Object.keys(o).filter(k => o[k] === maxValue)
}

console.log(getMaxKey(o));
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться методом `reduce`:

```
Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, curr) => acc[1] > curr[1] ? acc : curr)[0]
```